# How to SSH to s virtual machine from s Linux host?

Tags: linux, ssh, virtual-machine

I have a virtual machine which I launch using following code.

```
kvm -m 2G -hda image.raw -hdb image.data.qcow2 -redir tcp:11180::80
```

How can I transfer files from a Linux host to the virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer files using SCP protocol working on the same port as SSH. For that you need to redirect the port 22 on the virtual machine to a local port (`2222` in this example):

```
kvm -m 2G -hda image.raw -hdb image.data.qcow2 -redir tcp:11180::80 -redir tcp:2222::22
```

and connect with `ssh` to that port:

```
ssh -p 2222 user@localhost
```

To transfer files you can then use `scp`:

```
scp -p 2222 file.txt user@localhost:file.txt
```

Comment: But it require password. How can i fix this issue?

Comment: @ankitkumar How can I know? You need to provide the correct password to your virtual machine.

Comment: Sorry i asked stupid question. i logged in successfully by passing username and entering password.

Comment: If you're automating this while at the same time increasing security, you can also turn on Public Key Authentication instead of password authentication.

Comment: I cannot scp file and there is permission denied while i can login using the same username and passowrd.scp -p 2222 data.sql  user@localhost:file.txt

Comment: You must be more specific and show actual error messages (and probably inn a separate question, as the problem has different reason than port forwarding and SSH access).