# cannot trasnfer files from host to virtual machine using scp

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox, scp

This refers to my previous question ..

[How to SSH to s virtual machine from s Linux host?](https://superuser.com/questions/1119060/how-to-ssh-to-s-virtual-machine-from-s-linux-host)

i could login but when i trasnfer files using scp it does not work.

```
scp -p 2222 temp.sql  user@localhost:temp
user@localhost's password:
```

i tried filezilla also but it does not work.

[image]

Permission denied, please try again.

While i am using the same username and password. May i know how can i fix this pblm.

Comment: your virtual machine is `localhost`? Do not connect through Quickconnect, but select SFTP when doing proper connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try on port 2222:

```
scp -P 2222 temp.sql  user@localhost:temp
```

Comment: sorry it does not work....

Comment: @ankitkumar login into the virtual machine on second terminal. Check that you have write permissions on the folder you'll end up in.

Comment: yes i have permision to do that as i just created one file(data) using touch data